# I tried to mount Windows partion "/dev/sda1 by terminal but But it mounted directly on the /media

Tags: mount, unmount

how to fix this and How to mount /dev/sda1 in /media with specific
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGWyX.png)

Answer (score 1):

- **unmount**

  ```
  sudo umount /dev/sda1
  ```
- **create mountpoint**, select a name that is easy to remember (only once)

  ```
  sudo mkdir /media/sda1
  ```
- **mount**

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/sda1
  ```

You may want to **modify the permissions and ownership**. This problem is typical for partitions with a Microsoft file system, NTFS, FAT32 and exFAT. The ownership and permissions are set when mounting and cannot be modified without unmounting and mounting again, this time with new settings.

See this link with more details,

- [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072)